# execute simple javascript as chrome add-on

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I trying to create a simple google chrome add on, that should hide an div id on youtube.
But nothing is happening, no errors, and I can't seem to inspect the add-on either.

Any suggestions? this is what i have for now.

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click AntiDistraction Button",
  "description": "This extension removes youtube sidebar.",
  "version": "1.0",


  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],

      "js": ["remove.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"

  }
}
```

remove.js file

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("watch7-sidebar").style.display="none";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `matches` to include youtube.
At the moment - this will only load on google.com as per your `matches`

```
"matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],
```

See: [Match Patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) for more details

Comment: oooo Im so dumb, got totally blind with the javascript. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to change youtube pages but are injecting your script only in google.com pages.

Also, you probably [don't need](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to listen for `window.onload` to execute your code:

> Note: With "document_idle", content scripts may not necessarily receive the window.onload event, because they may run after it has already fired. In most cases, listening for the onload event is unnecessary for content scripts running at "document_idle" because they are guaranteed to run after the DOM is complete. If your script definitely needs to run after window.onload, you can check if onload has already fired by using the document.readyState property.

To debug your content scripts, open the Chrome Developer Tools for the page where they were injected, and in the sources panel you'll find a tab named 'Content Scripts'.

And on a side note, you don't need a `browser_action` section in your manifest if you are not specifying a popup window or listening to `browserAction` events.

Comment: Thank you so much. i got totally blind here :)